# why my datatable dosent work when I have huge data?

Tags: laravel, datatable

I am using a datatable in my laravel project for huge data. It's about 78000 rows and 30 columns.
I get this error :

```
DataTables warning: table id=dt-basic-example - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7
```

When I insert smaller data everything works good and no error appears.

I went to this url : [enter link description here](https://datatables.net/tn/7)

I do every step but it return this : This request has no response data available

What can I do?

My controller :

```
$ProducerCompanies = \App\ProducerCompanies::all()->where('Activation',$company);
        return DataTables::of($ProducerCompanies)
            ->addColumn('id', function ($ProducerCompanies) {
                if ($ProducerCompanies->Activation == '0') {
                    $data = "bg-danger" . '/' . $ProducerCompanies->id;
                } elseif ($ProducerCompanies->Activation == '1') {
                    $data = "bg-success" . '/' . $ProducerCompanies->id;
                }
                return $data;
            })
            ->addColumn('IdCategory', function ($ProducerCompanies) {
                $id = $ProducerCompanies->category->name;
                return $id;
            })
            ->addColumn('action', function ($ProducerCompanies) {
                $id = $ProducerCompanies->id;
                return $id;
            })
            ->addColumn('country', function ($ProducerCompanies) {
                if ($ProducerCompanies->industrialname != '') {
                    $id = $ProducerCompanies->countryname->name . '/' . $ProducerCompanies->statename->name . '/'
                        . $ProducerCompanies->cityname->name . '/' . $ProducerCompanies->industrialname->name;
                } else {
                    $id = $ProducerCompanies->countryname->name . '/' . $ProducerCompanies->statename->name . '/'
                        . $ProducerCompanies->cityname->name;
                }
                return $id;
            })
            ->addColumn('Info', function ($ProducerCompanies) {
                $data = $ProducerCompanies->Information;
                return $data;
            })
            ->addColumn('product', function ($ProducerCompanies) {
                if ($ProducerCompanies->leaders->count() != 0) {
                    foreach ($ProducerCompanies->leaders as $row) {
                        if ($row->where('Activation', '1')->count() === $row->count()) {
                            $data2 = 'bg-success';
                        } else if ($row->where('Activation', '1')->count() >= 0) {
                            $data2 = 'bg-danger';
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    $data2 = 'bg-danger';
                }
                if ($ProducerCompanies->certificate->count() != 0) {
                    foreach ($ProducerCompanies->certificate as $row2) {
                        if ($row2->where('Activation', '1')->count() === $row2->count()) {
                            $data3 = 'bg-success';
                        } else if ($row2->where('Activation', '1')->count() >= 0) {
                            $data3 = 'bg-danger';
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    $data3 = 'bg-danger';
                }
                if ($ProducerCompanies->product->count() != 0) {
                    foreach ($ProducerCompanies->product as $row3) {
                        if ($row3->where('Activation', '1')->count() === $row3->count()) {
                            $data4 = 'bg-success';
                        } else if ($row3->where('Activation', '1')->count() >= 0) {
                            $data4 = 'bg-danger';
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    $data4 = 'bg-danger';
                }
                $data = $ProducerCompanies->id . '/' . $data2 . '/' . $data3 . '/' . $data4;
                return $data;
            })
            ->make(true);
```

My script in HTML page :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#dt-basic-example").dataTable({
                serverSide: true,
                processing: true,
                ajax: {
                    url: '/ProducerCompanies/ajax/{{ $company }}',
                    data: function (data) {
                        data.params = {
                            sac: "helo"
                        }
                    }
                },
                scrollY: 500,
                srollX: true,
                ScrollCollapse: true,
                columns: [
                    {data: "id",className: 'id'},
                    {
                        "data": "Logo40",
                        name: "Logo40",
                        render: function (data) {
                            return "<div style='width: 50px;height: 50px'><img class='w-100 h-100' src='/" +
                                data + "'></div>"
                        },
                        orderable: false,
                        searchable: false
                    },
                    {"data": "Name"},
                    {"data": "CompanyId", searchable: false},
                    {
                        "data": "IdCategory",
                        name: "IdCategory",
                        render: function (data) {
                            return "<div>" + data + "</div>"
                        }
                        , searchable: false
                    },
                    {"data": "CreateTime", searchable: false},
                    {"data": "created_at", searchable: false},
                    {
                        "data": "action",
                        name: "action",
                        render: function (data) {
                            return "<div class='d-flex justify-content-center'>" +
                                "<div style='width: 50px;height: 35px'>" +
                                "<a class=\"btn btn-primary d-inline-block w-100 h-100\"\n" +
                                "href=\"/ProducerCompanies/index/" + data + "/edit\">" +
                                " <i class=\"fal fa-edit text-white\"></i></a></div>\n" +
                                "<div style='width: 50px;height: 35px'>" +
                                "<button class=\"btn btn-danger btn-sm text-white w-100 h-100 destroy ml-2\"" +
                                " value='" + data + "'>\n" +
                                "<i class=\"fal fa-trash-alt\"></i>\n" +
                                "</button></div></div>\n"
                        }, searchable: false
                    },
                    {"data": "CompanyNumber", searchable: false},
                    {"data": "FactoryNumber", searchable: false},
                    {"data": "FaxNumber", searchable: false},
                    {"data": "CompanyAddress", searchable: false},
                    {"data": "FactoryAddress", searchable: false},
                    {"data": "BackgroundImg", searchable: false},
                    {"data": "InformationImg", searchable: false},
                    {"data": "CompanyEmail", searchable: false},
                    {"data": "CompanyWebsite", searchable: false},
                    {
                        "data": "country",
                        name: "country",
                        render: function (data) {
                            return "<div><img class='mr-2' style='width: 25px;' src='/images/iran-flag.jpg'>" +
                                data + "</div>"
                        }
                        , searchable: false
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "Info",
                        name: "Info",
                        render: function (data) {
                            return "<div style='max-width: 850px''>" + data + "</div>"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "product",
                        name: "product",
                        render: function (data) {
                            $data = data.split('/');
                            return "<a href='/product/" + $data[0] + "' " +
                                "class='btn btn-outline-primary float-right d-flex align-baseline'" +
                                " style='margin-top: 90px'>" +
                                "<i class='d-inline-block " + $data[3] + " rounded-circle mr-2 mt-1'" +
                                " style='width: 15px;height: 15px'></i>" +
                                "محصولات این شرکت</a>" +
                                "<a href='/company-leaders/" + $data[0] + "' " +
                                "class='btn btn-outline-primary float-right mr-2 d-flex align-baseline'" +
                                " style='margin-top: 90px'>" +
                                "<i class='d-inline-block " + $data[1] + " rounded-circle mr-2 mt-1'" +
                                " style='width: 15px;height: 15px'></i>" +
                                "مدیران این شرکت" +
                                "</a>" +
                                "<a href='/company-Certificate/" + $data[0] + "' " +
                                "class='btn btn-outline-primary float-right mt-2 d-flex align-baseline'>" +
                                "<i class='d-inline-block " + $data[2] + " rounded-circle mr-2 mt-1'" +
                                " style='width: 15px;height: 15px'></i>" +
                                "گواهی نامه های این شرکت</a>"
                        }
                    }
                    ]
                });
        });
```

Comment: Delete `all()` add `get()`  `$ProducerCompanies = \App\ProducerCompanies::where('Activation',$company)->get();`

Comment: no it didnt work

Comment: What the response you get? https://datatables.net/media/images/tn/1/chrome-4.png

Comment: It say This request has no response data available